# Zero tensor is the same for every coordinate system (proof)

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, tensors

The tranformation formula for tensors is 
$$
T^{'}_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n}=a_{i_1j_1}a_{i_2j_2}\dots a_{i_kj_k}T_{j_1j_2\dots j_n}
$$
Let $T_{j_1j_2\dots j_n}$ be the zero tensor.
If we call $A$ the matrix of direction cosines and $T^{'}$ is $T$ rotated, in an arbitrary coordinate system. How can I show that $T^{'}$ which given by
$$T^{'}_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n}=AT_{j_1j_2\dots j_n}
$$ is also the zero tensor?

Comment: Hi, your post seems to be lacking a clear question, it's unclear what you're trying to find out. Please edit the question

Comment: I want to prove that: If the components of a tensor are all zero for one given coordinate system, then they're zero for every coordinate system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components of the tensor in the new basis are linear combinations of the components in the old basis. The components in the old basis are all zero. So the components in the new basis will be a linear combination of a bunch of zeros. Thus they will be zero.